# http status 400 in iOS

Tags: java, ios, response, form-data

My web service has been prepared on JAVA platform. And to send request parameter, I need to use Form-Data. I am trying to get the response from my web service, but I am getting only this error every time.

```
    -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x71a7010 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}")
```

To call this web service, My code is this :

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webserviceURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
//this is hard coded based on your suggested values, obviously you'd probably need to make this more dynamic based on your application's specific data to send
NSString *postString = @"username=test123&password=rgs&gsf&emailid=rhiuhh@fgfggr.com";
NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];


NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ]; // send data to the web service
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *trimmedString = [returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSString *trimmedString1 = [trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
trimmedString1 = [trimmedString1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"json string %@",trimmedString);
NSMutableArray *dic = [trimmedString1 JSONValue];
NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [dic objectAtIndex:0];
return dic1;
```

Please help me to come out from this.

Find JSON string here :

```
    json string <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you post the results of NSLog(@"json string %@",trimmedString); It seems that your web service does not return a valid JSON string

Comment: I think there is not an issue of web service, because when I am checking it on browser, it gives me perfect response. Still I have updated my question with json string which I am getting in response.

Comment: what is gsf in your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the web service is a java spring-mvc.
It seems you don't pass the correct parameters to the server.
As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228484/spring-the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect) the most common problem to the error "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" is that the server expects other parameters than the ones you send.

Comment: Yes you are quite right!!! 

Actually I am not passing the correct parameter for content-type.

        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

It should be like this....

Thanks a lot!!!